# Customize Gallery View formatting of a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, modern-document-library

I'm looking for any assistance on how to change the formatting of the gallery view of a document library (not the tile view of a list, which is what all the search results end up being for). The default gallery view, regardless of what fields are displayed in the view when in list format, is a thumbnail of the document and the filename.

Ideally, I would like:

1. Bigger thumbnail, like in the highlighted content web part (which can't be customized as far as I can tell, so isn't a solution)
2. Display columns/data that I want, such as document title instead of the filename
3. Display download button/link (already set up as a field on the library, so I have the JSON set for this and it works in list view)

The Microsoft documentation isn't robust enough for a novice like me, and doesn't really touch on gallery view.